# PyInstaller and PythonNet CLR

Tags: python, .net, clr, pyinstaller, python.net

ok, I need some help with pyinstaller and PythonNet.

This is my first time posting to the forum and I'm relatively inexperienced with coding but I've been learning a little python for GUI development.  I've got a script that uses a .NET dll library to interface with a USB camera. The script runs properly in Python, but I'm trying to compile it to .exe via Pyinstaller and I'm getting stuck.

Here are the first few lines of code:

```
import os
import clr
import sys
import System
from System import IntPtr
```

And here's the error after running the compiled .exe file:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembl
>   y 'Python.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5000fea6cba7
>   02dd' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition doe
>   s not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String cod
>   eBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntro
>   spection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String code
>   Base, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& s
>   tackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntros
>   pection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName as
>   semblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMar
>   k& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIn
>   trospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>      at clrModule.initclr()

I think the issue with python.runtime is similar to the one posted here (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/34) but I've tried the recommended solution and I'm still getting the same error. i.e. I uninstalled pythonnet and then searched for and deleted any remaining clr.pyd or python.runtime.dll files.  Then re-installed using pip via the command prompt:

> "pip install --pre pythonnet"

After compiling my script, python.runtime.dll appears in the "dist" folder along with the exe file.  But there's something weird going on with the version numbers.  Right clicking the dll and viewing "properties" in windows lists the version as 2.0.0.2, but viewing the assembly info (with dotPeek) for the same file it is listed as 4.0.0.1.  What's going on here?

Here are the screenshots showing the version discrepancy:

[dll assembly screenshot shows version 4.0.0.1](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/702x235q90/661/FLbf3n.jpg)

[windows properties screenshot showing version 2.0.0.2]

imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/381x520q90/902/6DEzLM.jpg 
(sorry, I can't make this one a link)

Please note I'm running Python 2.7 (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit).  Also, initially I got an error during compiling because Pyinstaller couldn't find the python.runtime.dll needed by CLR, but I modified the clr-hook.py to include the full dll path, so now it compiles without error but something is still clearly not right. Here's the new hook:

```
    ##hook-clr.py 

    import ctypes.util  
    datas = [(ctypes.util.find_library('C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Python.Runtime'), '')]
```

And here's the output of pyinstaller during compilation:

```
C:\Users\M80\Desktop\RealTimeBeamAnalysis> pyinstaller Realtime_3_exec.py

219 INFO: wrote C:\Users\M80\Desktop\RealTimeBeamAnalysis\Realtime_3_exe
c.spec
263 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
455 INFO: ... resource update available
462 INFO: UPX is not available.
516 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
697 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
703 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
804 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
986 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
1118 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
1137 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
2354 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
2360 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
2519 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
2970 INFO: Processing hook hook-clr
3061 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
3298 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with C:\Users\M80\Desktop\RealTimeBeamAn
alysis
3299 INFO: checking Analysis
3299 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
3299 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
3299 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable

3393 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
022.8_none ...
3394 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc
8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91.manifest
3413 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
3414 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll
3414 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
3414 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcp90.dll
3416 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
3416 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcm90.dll
3541 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.e
gg\PyInstaller\loader\_pyi_bootstrap.py
3562 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
3582 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
3608 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
3748 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
3752 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
3840 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
3996 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
4131 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
4654 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
4657 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
4799 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
5021 INFO: Processing hook hook-clr
5094 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
5378 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
5513 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.e
gg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py
5680 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.e
gg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_archive.py
5831 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.e
gg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_carchive.py
5963 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_-py2.7.e
gg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_os_path.py
5982 INFO: Analyzing Realtime_3_exec.py
6026 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4
6038 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtCore
6322 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtGui
8180 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib
8298 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL
8386 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.Image
9391 INFO: Processing hook hook-distutils
9837 INFO: Processing hook hook-parser
10396 INFO: Processing hook hook-sysconfig
10493 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml
10580 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.sax
10618 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat
11866 INFO: Processing hook hook-setuptools
12416 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com
12434 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com.client
12562 INFO: Processing hook hook-pythoncom
12647 INFO: Processing hook hook-pywintypes
12771 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32ui
13937 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.special._ufuncs
13979 INFO: Processing hook hook-Image
14680 INFO: Processing hook hook-pycparser
15338 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin
15522 INFO: Processing hook hook-_tkinter
15863 INFO: checking Tree
15865 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
15866 INFO: building Tree out00-Tree.toc
16239 INFO: checking Tree
16240 INFO: building because out01-Tree.toc missing or bad
16241 INFO: building Tree out01-Tree.toc
16338 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph
18598 INFO: Processing hook hook-pytz
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py:11: MatplotlibDe
precationWarning: QT3-based backends are deprecated and will be removed after th
e v1.2.x release. Use the equivalent QT4 backend instead.
  mplDeprecation)
33262 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib.backends
34985 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtOpenGL
34990 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtSvg
35388 INFO: Processing hook hook-anydbm
36676 INFO: Processing hook hook-h5py
40292 INFO: Processing hook hook-IPython
46546 INFO: Processing hook hook-OpenGL
47113 INFO: Processing hook hook-OpenGL_accelerate
49549 INFO: Processing hook hook-zmq
50545 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom
50582 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom.domreg
55157 INFO: Processing hook hook-docutils
56850 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments
57268 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.lexers
57973 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.formatters
58388 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.styles
60513 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlite3
62490 INFO: Processing hook hook-lxml.etree
62500 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.etree.cElementTree
62529 INFO: Processing hook hook-_elementtree
63798 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
63799 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
63799 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
63805 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py
64029 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Image.py
64170 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py
64285 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
64420 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mpldata.py
64534 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
64672 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_PIL_Image.py
64797 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1.1dev_
-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Tkinter.py
70305 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of
final executable
73703 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.MFC to dependent assemblies of final executabl
e
73792 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.2
1022.8_none ...
73792 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86.manifest
73804 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
73804 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfc90.dll
73805 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
73805 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfc90u.dll
73805 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
73805 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfcm90.dll
73805 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
73807 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86\mfcm90u.dll
84271 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
99841 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\M80\Desktop\RealTimeBeamAnalysi
s\build\Realtime_3_exec\warnRealtime_3_exec.txt
99993 INFO: checking PYZ
99995 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
99996 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
137450 INFO: checking PKG
137450 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
137450 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
137516 INFO: checking EXE
137518 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because Realtime_3_exec.exe missing
137519 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
137590 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\M80\Desktop\RealTimeBeamA
nalysis\build\Realtime_3_exec\Realtime_3_exec.exe
137690 INFO: checking COLLECT
137690 INFO: building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I would very much like to hear how.

Comment: I have this exact problem, but with py2exe rather than pyInstaller - any resolution yet?

Comment: is Python.Runtime.dll in dist folder generated by PyInstaller?

Comment: @boileau see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pull request was merged to pyinstaller with a hook for clr (pythonnet):

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/2048/files

The proper way to use this clr hook is to specify `--hidden-import=clr` from command-line or `hiddenimports=['clr']` in spec file.
This should take care of finding `Python.Runtime.DLL` hidden import for Windows.

If anyone is willing to tackle bundling on Linux or OSX, then please go ahead! Note that Mono is not pre-installed on these platforms, hence bundling could get very complicated.